# Describing all models of the theory of $(\mathbb{Z}, =, S, 0)$

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider the theory of integers with equality, a constant 0 and the successor operation. In other words, that's a theory with axioms

- { axioms of equality },
- $\forall x \forall y (S(x) = S(y) \rightarrow x = y)$,
- $\forall x \exists y (S(y) = x)$,
- $\forall x \lnot (x = S(x))$,
- $\forall x \lnot (x = S(S(x)))$,
- $\forall x \lnot (x = S(S(S(x))))$,
- and countably infinite number of similar axioms each stating that $k$ applications of $S$ don't cycle.

What would be the models of this theory?

Clearly, one example is $\mathbb{R}$ with the natural interpretation. It just decomposes to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$, so we have $\mathfrak{c}$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ that don't care about each other. This suggests that for every uncountable cardinality $\alpha$ we can do something similar and decompose that into $\mathbb{Z} \times \alpha$ (and similarly for countable models of the form $\mathbb{Z} \times k$, where $k$ is finite or countably infinite). But is there anything else?

If there is, how does it look? If there isn't, does it mean that this theory is uncountably categorical? The latter would be interesting, since this theory clearly isn't countably categorical.

Comment: @coffeemath nope, as I'm considering all integers, not just non-negative ones. On the second thought, $0$ probably isn't necessary at all.

Comment: Also, do you require $=$ to be interpreted as actual equality?  (If not, then there are loads more models you can get because any element of a model can be replaced by some arbitrary equivalence class.)

Comment: @EricWofsey yep, I'm only considering normal models.

Comment: Why only consider $\alpha$ uncountable? I daresay  that any number of disjoint copies of $\Bbb Z $ and/or disjoint copies of (backwards) $\Bbb N$ works

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen right, good catch! For instance, $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}$ is also a model for this, which is $\mathbb{Z} \times 2$, and so is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$, for instance. I'll update the question.

Comment: Regarding something like $\text{backwards} \mathbb{N} + \mathbb{N}$ — looks like it's starting to get messy. I'm not sure we can say that it's the same as $\mathbb{Z}$ (even though it's isomorphic). So is there some concise way to sum it up instead of enumerating all such possibilities?

Comment: I suppose you want to add $\forall x\exists y (S(x)=y)$?

Comment: Doesn't it follow naturally from $S$ being a functional symbol and thus having to be defined on every $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a decomposition like this is always possible. Just look at the equivalence classes under the relation $x\sim y$ iff there is an $n$ such that $S^n(x) = y$ or vice versa. So all models can be expressed as disjoint copies of $\mathbb Z.$ It follows that the theory is $\kappa$-categorical for any uncountable $\kappa,$ but not $\aleph_0$-categorical (since the models with finitely many copies will not be isomorphic to each other or to models with countably infinite numbers of copies).

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: Let's say $M=(\Bbb Z,=, S, 0)$ to save typing. Note first it seems likely that you don't actually mean to include "$=$" in the signature, it seems more likely that you''re talking about the theory of $(\Bbb Z, S, 0)$ *in* first-order logic with equality. Assuming that:

It's not at all clear to me that the theory of $M$ is in fact characterized by those axioms, although it seems right. In any case, the models of those axioms are exactly $\Bbb Z\times A$ for some set $A$, with the obvious interpretation of $S$ (and with $0$ any element of the structure; note $0$ is never mentioned in the axioms).

This is clear. In any model $M'$ the interpretation of $S$ is a bijection such that no $S^k$ has a fixed point. Say $$O(x)=\{S^k(x):k\in\Bbb Z\}.$$Then the sets $O(x)$ give a partition of $M'$, and each $O(x)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I think these axioms do give the theory of M, since we can show the models have this structure from just the fact that $S$ is bijective and acyclic, and then completeness follows from the categoricity via Vaught's test.

Comment: The intuition I used (briefly outlined in a now-deleted comment) is that we can do quantifier elimination on $(\mathbb{Z}, =, S, 0)$ using just these properties of $S$ (being bijective and acyclic). So, for every formula $\phi$ of this theory there exists an equivalent quantifier-free formula $\psi$, which, for a closed $\phi$, means $\psi$ is either constantly true or false, meaning it (or its negation) has a derivation in this theory, which means the theory is complete. Though the reference to the Vaught's test is surely more rigorous, I should have used that.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Vaught's test, cool. Sure enough, for example any two moodels of cardinality $c$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @0xd34df00d Yes, it's overkill, but you can use QE to get to completeness here. But remember that QE doesn't always imply completeness. For instance, here you have a constant symbol (though as David notes, it's largely irrelevant). So there are quantifier-free sentences besides $\top$ and $\bot,$ and one would have to show they are all equivalent to  $\top$ or $\bot.$ (But that's not hard here.) Another way to see it follows from QE here is that $\mathbb Z$ embeds in every model, so it follows from the fact that QF statements are absolute upwards.

Comment: @0xd34df00d If you say so. Given that you thought QE proved the original incomplete set of axioms was complete you might want to write it out carefully. I'm happy with the argument from Vaught's test. Very simple - I'd never heard of Vaught but it didn't take me long to realize it was more or less obvious from Lowenheim-Skolem...